# Flexbox content going out of place when the screen height is reduce on laptop

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My page is working correctly both on laptop, phone and tablet, but I noticed if I resize the browser on the laptop for a smaller height the content goes all on top of each other. I have 3 containers. The 1st 2 have 2 boxes in a row(called column in the code).

[Like in the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K39Rg.png)

I understand the svg is difficult to control. How about the rest? Am I supposed to set queries for height as well?

*Edit: I added snippet but in the snippet the heights are not working as in my page.

```css
*,*:before,*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
      font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
} 
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(196, 17, 196);
}
.column1,
.column2 {
     flex: 50%;
}
.column2, .column1 {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
.column1 p {
       letter-spacing: 0.09rem;
     font-size: 3.75rem;
       font-weight: 600;
       text-transform: uppercase;
}
.column2-text {
       position: relative;
       padding-left: 5%;
       margin-top: 20%;
       color: rgb(249, 248, 246);
}
.column2-text h1 {
       letter-spacing: 0.09rem;
     font-size: 3.75rem;
       font-weight: 600;
       text-transform: uppercase;
}   
.column2-text p {
       font-size: 1.125rem;
       font-weight: 400;
       line-height: 1.875rem;
       margin-bottom: 2.188rem;
}
.container2 {
     display: flex;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgb(249, 248, 246);
}
.column3,
.column4 {
     flex: 50%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
.column3-text {
       width: 55%;
       color:rgb(35, 31, 32);
}
.column3-text h2, h3 {
       font-size: 1.875rem;
       font-weight: 500;
}
.column3-text p {
       font-size: 1.063rem;
       font-weight: 400;
       line-height: 2rem;
       padding-bottom: 15%;
} 
.container3 {
     height: 35%;
     background-color: #f3f1eb;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
     align-items: center;
}
footer{
       background-color: #edeae2;
       color:rgb(35, 31, 32);
       align-items: center;
       display: flex;
       height: 15%; 
}

@media screen and (max-width:820px) {

.container1, .container3, .column3, .column4 {
        flex-direction: column;
}
.container2{
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.container1{
        height: 100vh;
}
.column1{
        min-height:10%;
}
.column2{
        min-height:90%;
}
.column3{
        min-height:80%;
}
main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
}
.column3-text{
        width:80%;
        text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
       <div class="container1">
           <div class="column1">
              <p>small image</p>
           </div>
           <div class="column2">
               <div class="column2-text">
                   <h1>Call for<br>entries 2023</h1>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, nisi? Numquam optio ab tempore iusto id perspiciatis ut quod dolorem repudiandae dolore praesentium nostrum nesciunt totam in quam, temporibus necessitatibus.</p>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="container2">
           <div class=column3> 
                <div class="column3-text">
                                <h2>How we started </h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ut feugiat ligula. Donec rutrum est risus, quis feugiat ligula egestas ut. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam ipsum magna, iaculis at nulla sit amet, sollicitudin finibus dolor. Proin massa neque, ultricies nec erat ac, suscipit tincidunt sapien. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis.</p>
                                <h3>Where we are now</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris interdum nunc ac sapien semper rutrum. Ut nec consequat velit. Proin ut accumsan mi. Sed congue congue dui at consectetur. Fusce at euismod leo. Quisque facilisis nec leo sed.</p>
                         </div>
           </div>
           <div class="column4">
                <p>big svg image</p>
           </div>
             </div>
       <div class="container3">
            <p>link for email</p>
       </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>links for social media</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted your code to a snippet, but am unable to reproduce the problem. Suggest you edit your question, move your code into a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) and adjust it until you have a [minimial reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.column1, .column2 { 
  flex:50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.column2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container2 {
  display:flex;
  height: 100%;   
  border: 2px solid lime;
}
.column3, .column4 { 
  flex: 50%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}
.container3{
  height: 35%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid magenta;
}
@media screen and (max-width:820px){
.container1, .container3, .column3, .column4 {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container2{
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
</body>
<main>
    <div class="container1">
    <div class="column1">
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content<br>
        column1 content
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content<br>
        column2 content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class=column3>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content<br>
        column3 content
        </div>
        <div class="column4">
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content<br>
        column4 content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content<br>
        container3 content
    </div>
 </main> 
 <footer>
 </footer>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I did the snippet with mock text and simple text instead of the images. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Your adjusted snippet looks a lot better, but I still can't see a problem with it. You say that when you make the browser window less high that the content overlaps? I'm not seeing that.